# Is a disc that lands on top of a basket considered holed?

Tags: disc-golf

This is rare case, but in the event that a disc lands on top of a basket (above the chains and basket in the round area that is often on top of the goal) is it considered holed or does it require an additional throw to actually hole out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [PDGA competition rules](http://www.pdga.com/files/documents/Authoritative_Rules_QA_v12_2011.pdf):

QA7: Disc Resting on Top (DROT)

Q: I putted and my disc stayed on top of the basket. Now what?

A: You have not holed out. Mark your lie below the disc and continue.

- Applicable rules: 803.13 Holing Out; 803.08 Disc Above Or Below the Playing Surface